# ExpressJS Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, postman

initially successful for the hit request, but the second time failed. is there something wrong in my code? thank you

My error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

My Code =

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    OriginalPassword !== req.body.password &&
      res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SEC,
      { expiresIn: "3d" }
    );

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

    res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

First spread the values into your object then update the values

`const {  ...others, password } = user._doc`